# Column ambiguously defined error due to subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am a newbie at SQL and having tough time with the below query. I am trying to fetch users who have same role id as mine but I dont want the below query to return my name (hence I used u.id<>0 in AND condition). As I am admin user, I have multiple ROLES (R1, R2 and R3) assigned to me. I want the query to return all other users having ROLE R1.  The "column ambiguously defined.." error is coming due to subquery. My questions are -

1. What is the resolution of this error?
2. How can I pull users who have same role_id as I do? Can anybody tell me the correct query?

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || U.LAST_NAME AS USER_NAME,
    U.PHONE AS PHONE,
    U.EMAIL AS USER_EMAIL FROM USERS U
    INNER JOIN USR_ORG_DOM_ROLE_RELATIONS UODR ON U.ID=UODR.USER_ID
    INNER JOIN ROLES R ON R.ID=UODR.ROLE_ID
    WHERE
    U.DELETED='N'
    AND U.DISABLED='N'
    AND U.ID<>0
    AND R.ID=(SELECT ID FROM ROLES R 
    INNER JOIN USR_ORG_DOM_ROLE_RELATIONS UODR ON R.ID=UODR.ROLE_ID
    INNER JOIN USERS U ON U.ID=UODR.USER_ID
    WHERE U.ID=0);
```

Comment: To which line of your query is the error message pointing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ID` in the subquery needs an table alias...

Also, you can't use the same alias on two different table references.  even if they are the same table in two different places. Try this:

```
 Select Distinct u.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || u.LAST_NAME USER_NAME,
      u.PHONE, u.EMAIL USER_EMAIL 
 From Users u
    Join USR_ORG_DOM_ROLE_RELATIONS uodr
       On u.ID = uodr.USER_ID
    Join ROLES r 
       On r.ID = uodr.ROLE_ID
 Where u.DELETED='N'
    AND u.DISABLED='N'
    AND u.ID<>0
    AND r.ID = 
       (SELECT iR.ID FROM ROLES iR 
          JOIN USR_ORG_DOM_ROLE_RELATIONS iUODR 
             ON iR.ID=iUODR.ROLE_ID
          JOIN USERS iU 
             ON iU.ID=iUODR.USER_ID
        WHERE iU.ID=0);
```

or this if multiple roles can exist, (and are ok) for UserId = 0

```
 Select Distinct u.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || u.LAST_NAME USER_NAME,
      u.PHONE, u.EMAIL USER_EMAIL 
 From Users u
    Join USR_ORG_DOM_ROLE_RELATIONS uodr
       On u.ID = uodr.USER_ID
    Join ROLES r 
       On r.ID = uodr.ROLE_ID
 Where u.DELETED='N'
    AND u.DISABLED='N'
    AND u.ID<>0
    AND r.ID In 
       (SELECT iR.ID FROM ROLES iR 
          JOIN USR_ORG_DOM_ROLE_RELATIONS iUODR 
             ON iR.ID=iUODR.ROLE_ID
          JOIN USERS iU 
             ON iU.ID=iUODR.USER_ID
        WHERE iU.ID=0);
```

But I think this is the same as the following:

```
 Select Distinct u.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || u.LAST_NAME USER_NAME,
      u.PHONE, u.EMAIL USER_EMAIL 
 From Users u
    Join USR_ORG_DOM_ROLE_RELATIONS uodr
       On u.ID = uodr.USER_ID
    Join (Roles r Join USR_ORG_DOM_ROLE iuodr 
             On iuodr.Role_Id = r.Id
                And iuodr.UserId = 0)
        On r.ID = uodr.ROLE_ID
 Where u.DELETED='N'
    And u.DISABLED='N'
    And u.ID<>0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am getting following error -

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

I forgot to mention that I have multiple ROLES (R1, R2 and R3) assigned to me. I want other users with ROLE R1 to display. Sorry for lack of information.

Comment: This means that there is more than one role connected to UserId: 0...  To fix that, you would need to modify the subquery to only return one of those RoleIds,  or modify the Where clause so that it says `... AND R.ID IN ( [subquery here])`  I'm not sure which is more correct for what your business purpose is... But try my suggested rewrite...